# Java - What will be proper design/design pattern for this case?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have to listen to an event from an event emitting  class ;  for Example `click`. Current i have class which handles it the events from the event emitting  class  like this.

```
someclass.clickedOnItem1()
someclass.clickedOnItem2()
```

where someclass is

```
class Someclass {
   //functions clickedOnItem1() and clickedOnItem2()
}
```

note that `Someclass` does not implement an interface. My problem is that i want only certain subclasses of `Someclass` to have this behavior and have the capacity to override the behavior but also have some default behavior in class `Someclass`. The default behaviour of `Someclass` depends on specific behavior which is only available in certain subclasses. I was considering composition where each subclass can provide a custom  implemntation of an interface which handles click events. I am currently looking for advice on the best possible design pattern which can address this issue.

Comment: @Andrew I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't answer the *what design pattern* question, but just considering OOP concepts: you can use abstraction in `SomeClass`, and:

- Declare abstract methods to obtain specifics from concrete classes
- Make the entry-point (event handling) methods final in `SomeClass` to freeze decision making based on subclass-supplied specific configuration. This is important to prevent subclasses from skipping logic you want to control in the superclass.

`SomeClass` can look like this:

```
abstract class Someclass {
    final void clickedOnItem1(){
        if(this.getConcreteOption()) {
             //do if concreteOption
        }

        this.performClickOnItem1Action();
    }

    void performClickOnItem1Action() {

    }

    abstract boolean getConcreteOption();
}
```

This will force subclasses to supply specific config, keeping control of the flow in the superclass, while at the same time allowing concrete classes to override behavior.

Subclasses can look like:

```
class SomeclassA {
    void performClickOnItem1Action() {
        //overriding this...
    }

    boolean getConcreteOption() {
        return true;//or false
    }
}

class SomeclassB {
    boolean getConcreteOption() {
        return true;//or false
    }
}
```